# how to change custom order attributes

Tags: attributes, orders

I installed a plugin from amasty. This plugin adds a field "delivery_date" and "delivery_time" attribute to each order.
[image]
Now I am creating orders manually too and now my question is how can I set custom fields to an order?

Comment: You probably installed the Delivery Date extension, didn't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to edit the Delivery Date values from the backend, just go with "Edit" from the order view page:

[image: If you need to edit the Delivery Date values from the backend, just go with "Edit" from the order view page.]

To set these values programmatically the following code will work, assuming you have `$orderId`:

```
$deliveryDate = Mage::getModel('amdeliverydate/deliverydate');
$deliveryDate->load($orderId, 'order_id');
$data = array(
    'date'         => 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    'tinterval_id' => '[ID], // if using time intervals, this is time interval ID, 
                             // selected from drop-down  
                             // (`amasty_amdeliverydate_tinterval` table)
    'comment'      => 'Text',
);
$deliveryDate->addData($data);
$deliveryDate->save();
```